# When/where/why is a size_t not a uint?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, implementation, size-t, uint

I've been getting a lot of criticism for using `uint` instead of `size_t`, but every time I check the toolchain I am working with turns out `size_t` is defined as a `uint`.

Are there any compiler implementations where `size_t` is actually not a `uint`? What are the grounds for that criticism?

Comment: What is a "uint"? Assuming you mean `unsigned int`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=b36d2ed363b5e1661e4a1a57d3a0e554-76238ab73c2fc168e6d731d9f34df389

Comment: You never know what the future is made of. `size_t` is standard, elegant and meanfull. Better using it :)

Comment: size_t make your code protable for every flatforms of computer will define their own size_t.

Comment: Compile your program with 64-bit compiler. You may get some warnings over this.

Comment: `size_t` is standard, `uint` is non-standard. Also on 64 bit architectures `size_t` will be 64 bit (unsigned) whereas `uint` could easily be 32 bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`size_t` is the "size matching the largest possible address range you can use in the machine" (or some words to roughly that effect).

In particular, `size_t` will be 64 bits on a 64-bit machine, and 32 bits on a 32-bit system.

I'm assuming `uint` is short of `unsigned int`, which is pretty much universally 32 bits (these days, some older systems would be using 16-bit integers). So on a 64-bit system, an `unsigned int` will be 32 bits still, although memory allocations, strings, etc can be larger than 32 bits in size - which would cause problems if you are trying to use `uint` for the size.

Comment: IIRC it's also required to be unsigned

Comment: The type for size_t is not guaranteed to be unsigned, but it's guaranteed to be "large enough for any memory allocation in the system". So it will never overflow (unless you use it "badly").

Comment: @MatsPetersson - don't have a 64 bit compiler right now, but I assume an `int` to be the CPU register width, and logically, and logically same for `uint`. Is that not the case?

Comment: @user2341104: while original intention of int was indeed to match natural register size, approaching 64 bit many ABIs decided it would be terrible waste and made it 32-bit even for 64 bit registered platforms

Comment: No, `int` is definitely not 64-bit on a typical 64-bit system (Windows, Linux, MacOS all use 32-bit `int`, and aside from Windows, `long` is 64 bit - Windows by tradition has a load of code that uses `long` in places that make more sense to be 32 bit, so they decided that `long long` is required for 64-bit values).